# Area of trapezoids vs . area of parallelograms

Tags: calculus, geometry

By definition parallelograms are special type of trapezoids. Given a trapezoid
with known sides one can calculate its area according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid#Area). But in order to calculate the area of a parallelogram you need to know its height. I find this paradoxical. Can someone help clarifying this?

Edit: What I think I want to know is why trapezoid in general are solid(if that's the right word) but parallelograms are not. Rhombi are parallelograms. I can imagine changing a rhombus's  diagonals (hence its area) without changing its sides.

Answer (score 0):

There is no paradox.  The area of a trapezoid can be given by $$A = (b_1 + b_2)h/2,$$ where $b_1$ and $b_2$ are the lengths of the two parallel sides, and $h$ is the distance (height) between the parallel sides.

In a parallelogram, we have the special case $b_1 = b_2 = b$, thus the formula reduces to $$A = (2b)h/2 = bh.$$

Comment: what I meant was you have to know the height of a parallelogram to find its area you cannot calculate the area of a parallelogram just by its sides.

Comment: This is because, given the side lengths of a trapezoid **and** knowledge of which two sides are parallel, a general (nondegenerate) trapezoid has more information about its shape than a parallelogram.  A trapezoid will have in general four unique side lengths.   A parallelogram has only two.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Wikipedia formula involves the denominator $|b-a|$ which becomes $0$ in the case of the parallelogram; i.e. the formula only applies for non-parallelogram trapezoids.